# Unix shell: get each header of a file in one line

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Let us have a file whose headers are of the form:

```
head_name_1 head_name_2 head_name_3 ... head_name_N
```

Assume that the delimiter is a tab (so we don't need to specify it if we use the `cut` command in some way) I would like to find a bash shell command that prints the following in the standard output:

```
head_name_1
head_name_2
head_name_3
...
head_name_N
```

Assume we don't know N in advance (I know how to find it if necessary):

***Ideal solution***: using a command that doesn't need to explicitely compute N.

***Alternative solution***: finding N first and then doing something like

```
for i in 1 ... N; do head -1 file | cut -f$i; done
```

I have some problems with this second solution:

- I could do a `while` statement incrementing the value of $i, but my terminal doesn't recognise neither [ ] nor [[ ]] properly for comparison.
- If I want to use a `for` statement, I don't know how to generate the list of numbers from 1 to N.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To replace all tab by newline:

```
tr '\t' '\n' <file >new_file
```

Answer (score 1):

`tr` is really simple. An alternate solution:

```
head -1 file | xargs -d '\t' printf "%s\n"
```